# Gmail auto response body

Tags: email, gmail, response

I got this code here and it works great!
Just one question, how I can modify it so I can reply and keep the original message (body of the incoming email, unchanged) in my reply message? So people can see what they wrote in their original message and not only my reply. Like as I forward them my incoming message and add my reply on a top.

The code I have:

```
function RespondEmail(e) {

  // set response mail
  var responsebody = "MY TEXT";

  //send response email
  var threads = GmailApp.search("to:(my@gmail.com) label:unread");
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: responsebody, from: "my@gmail.com"});}

  // mark all as read
  var threads = GmailApp.search("to:(my@gmail.com) label:unread");
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
}
```

It works great, but how can I add the original incoming email to the responsebody?

It's for Gmail script on script.google.com

Thanks!!!

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

### Modification points :

- Retrieve the original message from the searched mail using `getBody()`.

  - If you want to send the text message, please use `getPlainBody()` instead of `getBody()`.
- Add the retrieved original-message to `responsebody`.

### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: responsebody, from: "my@gmail.com"});
}
```

#### To :

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var msg = threads[i].getMessages();
  var reply = responsebody + "\n\n" + msg[msg.length - 1].getBody();
  threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: reply, from: "my@gmail.com"});
}
```

### Note :

- In this modified script, the latest message is used as the original message.

  - If you want to use all messages in the thread, please modify as follows.

    - From `msg[msg.length - 1].getBody()` to `msg.map(function(e){return e.getBody()}).reverse().join("\n\n")`.
- In this modified script, it uses `"\n\n"` to between `responsebody` and the original message.

  - Please modify this for your situation.

### Reference :

- [getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody())

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.